# ¿Cómo arreglar el siguiente error: File is not a zip file?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

Quiero hacer un bucle que lea los archivos excel que tengo en una carpeta llamada curvas y guardarlos en una lista para posteriormente hacer una serie de instrucciones para cada uno de ellos. He probado el siguiente código pero me aparece el error que nombro en la pregunta y no sé como solucionarlos:

```
# Ruta de la carpeta que contiene los archivos Excel
ruta = "./curvas/"

# Obtener la lista de archivos en la ruta especificada
archivos_excel = os.listdir(ruta)

# Lista para almacenar los DataFrames generados
lista_dataframes = []

# Iterar sobre cada archivo Excel en la lista
for archivo in archivos_excel:
if archivo.endswith(".xlsx"):
    # Construir la ruta completa del archivo
    archivo_ruta = os.path.join(ruta, archivo)

    # Leer el archivo Excel en un DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(archivo_ruta, header=None, engine='openpyxl')

    # Agregar el DataFrame a la lista
    lista_dataframes.append(df)

# Imprimir los DataFrames almacenados en la lista
for df in lista_dataframes:
   print(df)
```

Comment: y todos son xlsx o tienes alguno xls?

Comment: @Alfabravo todos los que tengo son xlsx

Comment: Podria ser que alguno de los archivos estuviera corrompido?